# How to get value in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I have tried a lot of times but I did not how to retrive a value from XML using Java.  I tried to use DOM and Xpath.  Please help.  I can use a String Writer to printout the XML so I know the XML is not empty.

```
Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/temp_f/text()");


Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
}
```

The content of XML :

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
  <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
    <current_conditions>
        <condition data="Clear"/>
        <temp_f data="49"/>
        <temp_c data="9"/>
    </current_conditions>
  </weather>
</xml_api_reply>
```

It seems that it did not go in to the for loop because `nodes` is null.

Comment: You may write a simple helper class to accomplish your task around DOM. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346867/851432

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath expression evaluates to the (non existant) text-nodes underneath `temp_f`. Yet, you need the value of the data attribute:

```
/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/temp_f/@data
```

may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this implementation?

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: What does that really have to do with the question?